# a simple c++ concatenate/split string and integer in a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am new to C++ programming. I have a string and an integer and I want to merge them into one char array and after that I want to split it and get the string and the integer. I worked a piece of code and it almost works. The only problem is that it sometimes creates some garbage at the end of the string. I searched this forum but I didn't get a suitable solution. What am I doing wrong? Is there a simpler solution? Thank you in advance. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "string: ";
    char my_string[64];
    cin >> my_string;
    int i = 666;
    char i_size[8];
    sprintf( i_size, "%9d", i );
    strcat( my_string, i_size );
    cout << my_string << endl;
    char temp1[9] = { 0 };
    strncpy( temp1, my_string + ( strlen( my_string ) - 9 ), 9 );
    int in = atoi( temp1 );
    cout << "int = " << in << endl;
    char temp2[strlen( my_string ) - 9];
    strncpy( temp2, my_string, strlen( my_string ) - 9 );
    cout << "string = " << temp2 << "|" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
[corneliu@localhost prog-build]$ ./prog
string: e
e      666
int = 666
string = e|
[corneliu@localhost prog-build]$ ./prog
string: wewewewe
wewewewe      666
int = 666
string = wewewewe�@|
[corneliu@localhost prog-build]$
```

Comment: Your code uses C functions and C headers. These are considered non-idiomatic C++ and should be avoided.

Comment: Just a first glance: `cin >> my_string;` this is UNSAFE. Either specify the maximum amount to read via `cin >> setw(64) >> my_string;` (via `<iomanip>`) or even better: use a `std::string` from `<string>`. (Oh, and there are more of them: `sprintf` and `strcat`.)

Comment: `char temp2[strlen( my_string ) - 9];` this -- variable length arrays -- is a gcc extension, or C99, or C++1y, but not currently allowed in C++ (98/03/11). Even in C++1y, I'd rather say it's not recommended. Either `std::string` or `std::vector` or even `new char[strlen(my_string)-9]` should be better.

Comment: I guess the actual problem comes from this: `char temp2[strlen( my_string ) - 9];`. It seems to me the space for the terminating `\0` is missing in the array. *Note:* `strncpy` does *not* terminate the destination with a `\0` if the buffer is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working with fixed sizes and if they are larger then 7 chars in your case, it will produce garbage.

Guess since you want to code in C++, you should stay away from C "string-functions"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void main( ... )
{
   int my_int = 666;
   cout << "string: ";
   string my_string;
   cin >> my_string;

   // concat - separated by semicolon in this example
   stringstream ss;
   ss << my_string << ";" << my_int;

   cout << "string and int in one string: "
         << ss.str().c_str() << endl;

   // split
   string tmpStr = ss.str();
   size_t found = tmpStr.find(";");
   while( found != string::npos  )
   {
      cout << tmpStr.substr(0, found).c_str() << endl;
      tmpStr = tmpStr.substr( found+1 );
      found = tmpStr.find(";");

      // this case is true for the last part
      if( found == string::npos )
         cout << tmpStr.c_str() << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Depending on what you want to do with it you may need to try to convert each string-parts to an integer and if it fails you know its a string otherwise you can assign it to an integer.

I think, even this approach is not what i would really do in productive code, it should give you a hint how to do what you want to do from there.

Comment: Also, if you include `<string>`, it shouldn't be necessary to use `c_str()` if you want to output a `std::string` via an ostream.

Comment: yeah @DyP i forgot, "bad habit" to always use `wcout` since in most of my projects due to unicode support we only use wcout :P Always thought (w)cout doesn't like strings only chars... but didn't compile this have no proper enviroment atm

Comment: You can always use an online (www) compiler, like [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com) or [that one](http://ideone.com). Insertion and extraction operators for `string` are defined in the header `<string>`.